# The precise reason why DRAM is slower to write than to read?

Tags: sdram

I just want to make sure I have my facts straight.

In the olden days when I was a teenager and the Internet was unknown outside of academia, I recall learning (I wasn't taught this per se) that writing to DRAM is slower than reading because it takes time to charge or discharge the capacitors inside each DRAM memory cell.

Is this still the case or was it ever?

Comment: Whoops - Thought that you were trying to edit your previous question.  Sorry for the noise...

Answer (score 6):

Yep, it's still the case. The principle behind DRAM is that of a capacitor (simply, 1 small transistor and one large one), while that behind SRAM is a latch, made from a few (more) transistors. DRAM has more capacitance. If you assume they have equal* input impedance, then it's straightforward to see that the DRAM RC-delay is slower than that of SRAM.

DRAM is cheap, though, so we still love it. SRAM is awesome, so we love it, too.

DRAM:
[image]
<sub>(source: [emrl.de](http://www.emrl.de/imagesArticles/DRAM_Emulation_Fig2.jpg))</sub>

SRAM:
[image]

*(They likely won't -- it's really matched to its reading circuitry, but who cares.)

Comment: I think they wanted to know about the non-symmetric read and write times on DRAM, not comparison to SRAM.

Answer (score 3):

A read cycle for a "traditional" DRAM required reading a row from the memory array into the row buffer and writing it back unchanged.  A write cycle required reading a row, altering it, and then writing it back.  Generally, one could not begin altering a row in memory until after it was read.  It would have been possible to design a DRAM which included a 'tag' bit for each addressable location so that one could start writing a row even before it was read, and the "tagged" locations would be automatically overwrite the read data in the row buffer, but I am unaware of any manufacturer ever having done this.  It would also have been possible to allow an entire row to be written at once without reading it at all, but I'm unaware of any manufacturer having done that either.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that "read" and "write" have [identical timings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAM#Memory_timing) on typical DRAM.

Perhaps someone was telling you about "Flash memory" timings.
Flash memory has relatively quick read times but much longer write times.
For example, with a Numonyx M25P80-VMW6G 75MHz 8 Mbit serial flash,
reading a sector of data (at 75 MHz) requires 7 milliseconds,
while erasing and writing new data to a sector is typically 0.6 seconds (max 3 seconds).

In other words, writing this flash memory typically takes 85 times as long as reading, and in the worst case writing a sector takes over 400 times as long as reading.
(That's not even taken into account the inefficiencies of partial-sector updating).

In my experience, the time it takes to erase and rewrite a particular sector of flash continues to increase with each erase/rewrite cycle,
but read times stay constant.

Comment: Related:  ["Today I read that flash write performance diminishes with use. I'm a heavy user. Should I change my behavior?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116791/today-i-read-that-flash-write-performance-diminishes-with-use-im-a-heavy-user)

Answer (score 3):

The reason DRAM takes longer to write is due to the sensitive nature of the DRAM bit, and the way the arrays are wired up. Essentially, these two parameters make it necessary to perform a read before any data is written.

Memory arrays, including DRAM, are usually arranged into a grid. The outputs of each bit are connected vertically, and the enable signals for each bit are connected horizontally. In order to read a bit of data, the horizontal enable signal, or word line, connects the entire row to the vertical wires known as the bit lines. Even if you only want a single bit in a large array, you must access the entire row. This reduced flexibility in routing is necessary to achieve the desired density in memory arrays.

DRAM is essentially an array of capacitors with switches. When designing these capacitors, they are only a fraction of the parasitic wiring capacitances of the vertical bit lines. Amplifiers connected to the bit lines can detect the small voltage change that occurs when a charged DRAM cell is connected to the bit line, and amplify it into a logic value that other circuitry and chips can use. Due to the charge sharing of the bit line capacitance and the DRAM cell capacitance, the data on a DRAM bit is effectively erased any time it is accessed. If you want to read a single DRAM bit, you must write the value back to the same bit. Thus, every time you read from DRAM, the cycle is read, then write.

Due to the grid nature of memory arrays, the number of bits in a row is usually much larger than the word size of the array. This means that if you want to read or write a word from a row, there will be bits that are activated by the word line that you didn't want to read or write. This data will be destroyed if nothing is done to preserve it. That means when you read, you must read the entire row, and write back the entire row. For writing, you must read the entire row, and then write back the data that you read along with the data you want to write. Thus, the procedure for writing data to the array is read, then write.

So we see that the procedure is essentially the same for both reading and writing: first read a row, and then write back the new contents. Reading happens first, so the data could be made available first if the process is a multi-cycle event. Writing could take the longest since the write doesn't occur until the end of the process. Historically, this may have been a multi-cycle process, but I have seen amplifiers for reading that will write back as soon as they know the value which makes it effectively a tie for reading and writing.

Comment: Did you look at my answer?  Do you think my understanding seems correct?

Comment: Yes, I did look at your answer. It seems correct, but I felt like the "read before write" needed to be justified. Also, you may be surprised with modern DRAM design, which has practically eliminated this issue. I didn't mean to dig up an old question, just wasn't paying close enough attention when I opened it.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked at DRAMs, though I've long thought that there should be some cache memory included within DRAM chips.  I'm not sure if process for manufacturing a significant volume of static cache would require adding many steps that would otherwise be useless for manufacturing the dynamic memory portion of the chip, but having a cache that could fetch an entire row at a time would seem advantageous.  On the other hand, the physical bus between the DRAM and the processor cache would probably be a limit.

Answer (score -2):

Upon writing you charge and discharge the tiny capacitor like cells in DRAM. One capacitor correspond to one bit so imagine if you have 1Gigabyte of those cells. And this charging and discharging takes more time than reading those cells.

Comment: Reading charges and discharges the cells by almost the exact same amount.  If half-rail is at 2.50 volts (assumption for numerical simplicity), a programmed "0" will be written as 0.10 volts or below and read back as 2.48 volts, while a programmed "1" will be written as 4.90 volts or above and read back as 2.52 volts.  Changing a "1" to a "0" will require discharging the cap from 2.52 volts to 0.10 volts, while reading a zero and then refreshing it so it will be readable again will require discharging from 2.48 to 0.10.  Not much difference.